# What is an example of a proof that explicitly relies on the law of excluded middle?

Tags: logic, intuition

I was talking with a friend about logic and I realized she might be an intuitionist. I was looking online for a proof that explicitly uses the law of excluded middle to see if she would have an issue with it, but we couldn't find anything she understood (she's not very good at math). The best example I could think of was the proof that an irrational number raised to an irrational power could be rational. She didn't understand it at all.

Can you think of an example of a proof that explicitly relies on the law of excluded middle that a lay person would probably understand? It doesn't have to be particularly mathematical in nature. In fact, the less math you assume she knows, the better.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_proof The proof that a power of an irrational number to an irrational exponent may be rational. If $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ is rational then we are done, else $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ is irrational but $(\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2})^\sqrt{2}=2$ which is rational. Hmm ... you say you already tried this. The following might be a bit silly, but let me try. I will not get wet because of rain tomorrow. Proof: if it does not rain, then I won't get wet (because it didn't rain). If it does rain, then I won't get wet, because I am going to take an umbrella with me (just in case :)

Comment: I'll try that one

Comment: You can see also the discussion in this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739972/is-there-a-simple-example-of-how-the-law-of-the-excluded-middle-can-be-inapplica) and the argument leading to [Russell's Paradox](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/).

Comment: My proof didn't work. I had to go to a math [workshop](http://topann.comyr.com/CurrSem.html), I was about to be late, could not locate my umbrella, looked outside the window and at seemed that it did not rain, so I rushed out without an umbrella. Well, it did rain (fortunately just a little bit), but obviously my proof was destroyed. One of the speakers presented a paper which ends with the Law of contradiction, something may both be and not be, negative distance for pmetrics. The idea is that in the real world with vast amounts of data one has to deal with contradiction, and even formalize it

Answer (score 2):

Consider [Euclid's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem) asserting that there are infinitely many prime numbers :

> Consider any finite list of prime numbers $p_1, p_2,\ldots, p_n$. Let $P$ be the product of all the prime numbers in the list : $P = p_1p_2 \ldots p_n$ and let $q = P + 1$.
>
> > Then $q$ is either prime or not [...].

---

See Euclid's original proof in [Elements, Book IX, Prop.20](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIX/propIX20.html) :

> Let A, B, and C be the assigned prime numbers. I say that there are more prime numbers than A, B, and C.
>
> Take the least number DE measured by A, B, and C [i.e. DE = least common multiple(A,B,C)].
>
> Add the unit DF to DE.
>
> > Then EF is either prime or not.

Comment: This use of the law of excluded middle can be eliminated: the argument in the "not" branch works just as well.

Comment: A proof that relies say on bivalence but not excluded middle; as sometimes a distrinction is placed between the two properties;

Comment: Perhaps if you can find a derivation that some continuous probability model satisfies Scotts infinite theorem, or the other theorems that are even infinitely axiomatiz-ableI suppose any argument that explicition is equates falsity of 'A', with 'not A' being true, whilst at the same upholding the general truth deflationary truth schema that A is equivalent to A being true. For example one where strong negation is considered to be reducible to negation 'not true that A, and true, that 'not A';

Comment: Maybe some claims in QM, perhaps, there was an issue that Gleason's theorem was not constructively provable at one point. I think that was put to rest. See Richman, Hellman and Cooke on this

Answer (score 0):

See Colyvans article where he explicitly mentions it *Colyvan, Mark*, [**The philosophical significance of Cox's theorem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ijar.2003.11.001), Int. J. Approx. Reasoning 37, No. 1, 71-85 (2004). [ZBL1093.68113](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1093.68113)..

I think Professor Colyvan that it Cox's "derivation" of the "axioms of probability" makes use of the law of excluded middle.